# check if there overlapping in 2 table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

i have 2 table , StudentRegsitre & Agenda ,

Agenda Table have  (AgendaId, MatirelId, InstructorId, ClassId, 
                          AddedDate, Semester, StartTime, EndTime, DaySchedule)
StudentRegsitre (Id, AgendaId , UserId )

need to check if there overlapping in studentRegsitre by checking StartTime , EndTime, DaySchedule , classid , for the student by passing studentId from ASP.NET C#
i try this :

```
GO
 Create procedure [dbo].[SP_OverLappingExists] (@AgendaId uniqueidentifier ,@UserId uniqueidentifier  )
 As Begin 
 Declare @CurrentAgendaId uniqueidentifier;
 declare @MatirelId uniqueidentifier;
 declare @InstructorId  uniqueidentifier;
 declare @ClassId  uniqueidentifier;
 declare @Semester nchar(10);
 declare @StartTime time(7);
 declare @EndTime time (7);
 declare @DaySchedule varchar(50);
 declare @UserIdNew uniqueidentifier;
 declare @AgendaIdNew uniqueidentifier;

        if exists (SELECT @CurrentAgendaId = Agenda.AgendaId,@MatirelId= Agenda.MatirelId,
              @InstructorId= Agenda.InstructorId,@ClassId= Agenda.ClassId,@Semester= Agenda.Semester,
              @StartTime= Agenda.StartTime,@EndTime= Agenda.EndTime,@DaySchedule= Agenda.DaySchedule, 
                         @UserIdNew= StudentReg.UserId, @AgendaIdNew= StudentReg.AgendaId 
    FROM         Agenda INNER JOIN
                          StudentReg ON Agenda.AgendaId = StudentReg.AgendaId
                           where StudentReg.UserId = @UserId
      )
      begin
      return 1 
      end
```

but it had error " Incorrect syntax near '='  " near @currentAgendaId = Agenda.AgendaId
is there any help , if there any better idea , please share it with me .!

p.s : it's Study case .

Comment: The syntax is incorrect the correct one is `select columnName1, columnName2... from table1 inner join table2 .. where ...`

Answer (score 0):

An `EXISTS` query doesn't return any columns, hence you can't assign a column value to a variable.

This is one case where using an asterisk to specify all columns doesn't affect performance.  Common usage is:

```
if exists ( select * from ... )
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if exists ( select 42 from ... )
```